# Inserting both XmlDocumentType and XmlDeclaration to XmlDocument

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have some trouble creating my XmlDocument class. This is what I've tried to do:

```
Dim myDoc = New XmlDocument()

Dim docType As XmlDocumentType = myDoc.CreateDocumentType("DtdAttribute", Nothing, "DtdFile.dtd", Nothing)
myDoc.XmlResolver = Nothing
myDoc.AppendChild(docType)

Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration = myDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15").BodyName, "yes")

Dim root As XmlElement = myDoc.CreateElement("RootElement")

myDoc.AppendChild(root)
myDoc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root)
```

This will result in error: Cannot insert the node in the specified location. Line throwing this error is `myDoc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root)`

Just cannot figure out this. Which order should I insert these elements? I've tried different orders but I think I'm just doing something totally wrong and this shouldn't even work in the first place :) But then how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Dim myDoc As New XmlDocument()
Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration = myDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15").BodyName, "yes")
myDoc.AppendChild(xmldecl)
Dim docType As XmlDocumentType = myDoc.CreateDocumentType("DtdAttribute", Nothing, "DtdFile.dtd", Nothing)
myDoc.XmlResolver = Nothing
myDoc.AppendChild(docType)
Dim root As XmlElement = myDoc.CreateElement("DtdAttribute")
myDoc.AppendChild(root)
```

Note that the root element name must be the same as the `name` parameter given to `XmlDocument.CreateDocumentType`.

You may find, however, that for building an XML document from scratch like this, it's easier to just use the `XmlTextWriter`:

```
Using writer As New XmlTextWriter("C:\Test.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15"))
    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteDocType("DtdAttribute", Nothing, "DtdFile.dtd", Nothing)
    writer.WriteStartElement("DtdAttribute")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
End Using
```

Comment: Hey, it worked :) Thank you very much. Currently I have a large class using XmlDocument so need to stick with that ;)